# Parameter pack and member function pointer type deduction

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, optional-parameters

I have a little issue with clang and parameter packages.

The clang version is:

```
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
```

I have a problem I managed to reproduce in the following snippet:

```
class Foo{
  public:
    int fIsOk;
    bool fIsNotOk;
    bool fTheThird;
    Foo() : fIsOk(5),fIsNotOk(false),fTheThird(true){}
    inline bool isOk() const {return fIsOk; }
    inline bool isNotOk() const {return fIsNotOk; }
    inline bool theThird() const {return fTheThird; }
    inline int is1(int yours1) const {return fIsOk+yours1; }
    inline bool is2(bool yours1,bool yours2) const {return fTheThird && yours1 && yours2; }
    inline bool getTrue() const {return true;}
};

class User{
  public:
    User() : pippo(){};
    template<typename T,class ...Args> T doIt(int i=2, T (Foo::*condition)(Args...)const = &Foo::getTrue,Args... args){
      return (pippo.*condition)(args...)+i;
    }
  private:
    Foo pippo;
};

int testParameterPack(){
  User pluto;
  std::cout<<pluto.doIt(1,&Foo::isOk)<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<pluto.doIt(2,&Foo::is1,1)<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<pluto.doIt(3,&Foo::is2,true,false)<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

At compilation time I get:
In file included from input_line_9:1:

```
[...]/testParameterPack.cxx:23:114: error: missing default argument on parameter 'args'
    template<typename T,class ...Args> T doIt(int i=2, T (Foo::*condition)(Args...)const = &Foo::getTrue,Args... args){
                                                                                                                 ^
[...]/testParameterPack.cxx:33:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'User::doIt<int, int>' requested here
  std::cout<<pluto.doIt(2,&Foo::is1,1)<<std::endl;
                   ^
[...]/testParameterPack.cxx:23:114: error: missing default argument on parameter 'args'
    template<typename T,class ...Args> T doIt(int i=2, T (Foo::*condition)(Args...)const = &Foo::getTrue,Args... args){
                                                                                                                 ^
[...]/testParameterPack.cxx:34:20: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'User::doIt<bool, bool, bool>' requested here
  std::cout<<pluto.doIt(3,&Foo::is2,true,false)<<std::endl;
                   ^
[...]/testParameterPack.cxx:23:114: error: missing default argument on parameter 'args'
    template<typename T,class ...Args> T doIt(int i=2, T (Foo::*condition)(Args...)const = &Foo::getTrue,Args... args){
```

Even if to me a parameter pack should (must) not require a default value.
Can someone explain why I observe this behaviour?
Thank you in advance for your help

gf

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.

I see that g++ compiles your code and that clang++ gives error.

In don't know who's right but I suppose that the problem arises from the fact that you can't write a function as follows

```
int foo (int a = 0, long b) // compilation error: no default value for b
 { return 0; }
```

I mean: when you have a default value for a parameter, all following parameters must have a default value.

So, when you write

```
template <typename T, class ... Args>
T doIt (int i=2, T (Foo::*condition)(Args...)const = &Foo::getTrue,
        Args... args)
 { return (pippo.*condition)(args...)+i; }
```

and call it with an empty list of variadic arguments

```
pluto.doIt(1,&Foo::isOk)
```

all goes well because you create

```
bool doIt (int i=2, bool (Foo::*condition)()const = &Foo::getTrue)
 { return (pippo.*condition)()+i; }
```

so all parameters have a default value

But when you call `doIt()` with a not empty list of variadic parameters, by example

```
pluto.doIt(2,&Foo::is1,1)
```

you ask for the implementation of a `doIt()` function

```
int doIt (int i=2, int (Foo::*condition)(int) const = &Foo::getTrue,
          int arg0)
 { return (pippo.*condition)(arg0)+i; }
```

where the first two parameter have a default parameter where the following (one or more) are without default value.

I repeat: I don't know if is right clang++ refusing your code or there are special rules regarding the variadic arguments. But, as far I understand, clang++ contest you this problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Indeed I agree with you: here the problem is the way clang handles parameter packs. The c++ standard states that parameter packs shall not require a default argument. Hence no surprise GCC is compiling with no issues. It seems to me that clang tries to interpret the pack as a standard variable. I found several similar reports here and there, but they where old (~2015) and apparently fixed. Not the same problem seems to arise again.

Comment: @jetstream - but the fact that the standard not require a default argument for variadic argument say us that a preceding argument can have one? I don't think so because I can't imagine how can be intended a value of the corresponding type: a value for the preceding argument o the first value for a variadic list? Waiting for the answer from a standard guru, I point to a g++ bug (or g++ not conformance, at least).

Comment: I see your point. I would rather say, however, that a variadic argument can be empty and that since the variadic nature it is difficult to make the variadic argument the first of the list or arguments, if one wants to take other parameters with pre-defined type. Combining these two behaviours makes necessary a choice: put the variadic at the end of the parameter list and forget the defaults or put it in front and get the other parameters by parsing it... Totally agree on waiting for a compiler guru! ;)